# Javascript date divide

Tags: javascript, date, divide

```
Date.prototype.copy = function () {
  return new Date(this.getTime());
};


Date.prototype.msPERDAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
Date.prototype.msPERHOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60; 

     Date.prototype.getDaysBetween = function(d) {

  d = d.copy();

  var diff = d.getTime() - this.getTime();

  var days = Math.floor((diff)/this.msPERDAY);
  diff = (diff)/this.msPERDAY;
  var hours = Math.floor((diff)/this.msPERHOUR);
  alert(hours);
  var time = new Array(days , hours);
  return time;
};
```

In this function i get the future date and using it at current date

future.date - current.date = milliseconds difference

here i get the difference between days, but i cant get the hours, minutes and seconds

can you tell me, how i need to divide after i get the difference between days

this is javascript, sorry for a stupid question but is a problem for me :(

Answer (score 0):

For the hours, you can just grab the decimal part of the result of `diff = (diff)/this.msPERDAY` and multiply that by 24. Try the following (also on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLUqB/):

```
Date.prototype.copy = function () {
  return new Date(this.getTime());
};


Date.prototype.msPERDAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
Date.prototype.msPERHOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60; 

Date.prototype.getDaysBetween = function(d) {

    d = d.copy();

    var diff = d.getTime() - this.getTime();
    console.log(diff);

    var days = Math.floor((diff)/this.msPERDAY);
    console.log(days);

    diff = (diff)/this.msPERDAY % 1; // get only the decimal part of this
    console.log(diff);

    var hours = diff * 24; // multiply the decimal part by 24 to get hours
    console.log(hours );

    var time = new Array(days , hours);
    return time;
};

var d = new Date('02/01/2012 05:00');
d.getDaysBetween(new Date('02/12/2012 13:00'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page http://psoug.org/snippet/Javascript-Calculate-time-difference-between-two-dates_116.htm